# Multiple long-running threads with Tornado

Tags: multithreading, tornado

I'm attempting to write a streaming server in Tornado where I want to have multiple long-running streams accessible via unique URLs with each stream also having a chat component. I ideally want to make each stream into its own thread and have new connections "join" a thread so as to allow people to chat with each other. Reading Tornado's documentation and source code, I wasn't able to find a clear way to do this.

Here is a sample of my code so far:

```py
import json

from tornado.websocket import WebSocketHandler

class StreamHandler(WebSocketHandler):
    active_streams = {}

    def open(self, stream):
        if not stream in StreamHandler.active_streams:
            active_streams[stream] = set()

        StreamHandler.active_streams[stream].add(self)

    def on_message(self, message):
        message = json.loads(message)
        stream = message['hash']
        data = message['data']
        for conn in StreamHandler.active_streams[stream]:
            conn.write_message(data)
app = Application([
    (r'/s/(.*)/sock', StreamHandler)
])
```

The above code works in that I can have a different URL for each stream and have messages sent to other connections in that particular stream, but I wasn't sure if this was the best way to achieve what I want.

I was thinking of extending my code to have some sort of `ThreadFactory` that would spit out threads for a new stream, but I don't really know how to go about doing that.

Any feedback about my line of thought and/or existing implementation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you feel like you need threads? Long running I/O connections like those in a chat application are exactly the kind of use-case Tornado is designed to handle in a single thread, via asynchronous I/O.

Comment: The reason I thought I needed threads was because of the streaming part of the application. Maybe this is my not understanding the concept too clearly, but I thought that applications that have long-running video/audio streams have each stream running in its own thread. Is my logic of using a class-level dict to store active connections for each stream the right way to go in this case? Thanks!